# msfvenom: how to output assembly of windows payload for inline assembly in C?

Tags: windows, metasploit, assembly, msfvenom, x86

My goal is to obfuscate metasploit `windows` payloads' assembly code (adding junk code to the payload itself), then adding the obfuscated shellcode to inline assembly in C. The issue is there is no format command line argument (`-f`) that provides an asm option. Does anyone know how to output only the assembly code of the payload rather than the opcodes/hex bytes? Is there a simplistic way to achieve this?

Comment: Thats still gonna get caught by defender

Comment: I have a million different ways to bypass windows defender, this would certainly help in AV evasion, especially when used in conjunction with various other techniques.

Comment: Use a disassembler on the PE output?

Comment: Which disassembler on linux would be useful? I know I could use this for linux binaries but I'm clueless on how to extract the asm code from a PE.

Comment: x64dbg should do it.

Comment: If someone could provide an example I'll accept the answer.

Comment: The issue is when disassembling with objdump or IDA, windbg etc you don't get the core payload you have to sift through the .text segment to find such, is there a more comprehensive and simplistic method to do this?